# How to normalize mixed continuous/discrete features for DNN?

Tags: neural-networks, normalization, continuous-data, discrete-data, deep-learning

I have had some success training my deep neural network (with ReLU hidden units) by first normalizing the features of my data set to zero-mean-unit-variance.

Each sample of my data set has 600+ values. Majority of them are continuous but a handful or columns are symbolic / discrete (represent by fixed range integers). Currently I just normalize all columns to zero-mean-unit-variance the same way. Should I only normalize the continuous value columns? Are there better data normalization strategies?

Comment: By continuous features do you mean something like spatial or temporal continuity? What type of data you are using?

Comment: They are financial models where numbers are percentage changes.

Comment: If adjacent features are mostly correlated (or continuous), I think that is also your case, I don't recommend feature based normalization. Instead sample based normalization would be better. That is simply subracting mean of each sample from itself and also dividing of each sample's std to itself. I'm not familiar with data type you mention, If you think that will eliminate some important information from the data, don't apply any normalization on continuous part.

Comment: thanks. will try your suggestion of sample based normalization. not normalizing seems to leave poor results though.

Comment: What do you mean by 'symbolic'? Are they categorical? If so, they should be converted to multiple binary variables.

Comment: @yasin.yazici , can you explain why sample based normalization would be better?

Comment: @felbo sample based normalization is used in image recognition as brightness/ contrast normalization. You can easly invision that substracting mean of an image from itself eliminated offset (brightness) from that image. And dividing by its std stretch the image into certain limits. If adjacent features are highly correlated, as in images, you don't want to apply feature normalization since it doesn't care about the relation between adjacent features.

Comment: Ah okay, I've only heard it referred as per-example mean subtraction, never that one would divide by std. But that makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

You said your integer-valued variables have a fixed range, which makes things relatively easy. You will need to encode them as *several* features rather than one.

- If they are **categorical** (there is no inherent natural order within them), you can use one-hot encoding (i.e. the "fifth option" is represented as (0,0,0,0,1,0,0)), this is the common practice.
- If they are **ordinal** (discrete, but with an order), using one-hot is possible, but it's even better to use (1,1,1,1,1,0,0). The closest reference I'm aware of is ["A neural network approach to ordinal regression"](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.1028v1.pdf).

PS: If they can assume arbitrarily high values, it depends on the problem and goals at hand. For example, they can be represented as one variable with an accordingly adjusted cost function.